# Rails 404 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'll just start by saying i have no knowledge of rails whatsoever but must find a solution to a rails problem.

Basically there is a form that uploads an image and after the upload is done it should redirect to a page that displays a thank you message. Right now the image upload is working but the redirection doesn't and it comes up with a error 404

this is the form:

```
<%= form_for(@weather_photo, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>

 <div class="identity">
        <p style="color: #00597C;font-weight: bold;">Τα στοιχεία σου</p>
          <div class="form-line">
            <%= f.label :first_name, 'Όνομα:' %><%= f.text_field :first_name, :size => 22 %>
        </div>
        <%=render :partial=>"/cmanager/error_msg",:locals=>{:field =>'first_name',:element=>@weather_photo}%>
        <div class="form-line">
            <%= f.label :last_name, 'Επίθετο:' %><%= f.text_field :last_name, :size => 22 %>
        </div>
          <%=render :partial=>"/cmanager/error_msg",:locals=>{:field =>'last_name',:element=>@weather_photo}%>
        <div class="form-line">  
            <%= f.label :email, 'Email:' %><%= f.text_field :email, :size => 22 %>
        </div>
          <%=render :partial=>"/cmanager/error_msg",:locals=>{:field =>'email',:element=>@weather_photo}%>
         <div class="form-line">  
            <%= f.label :description, 'Περιγραφή :' %><%= f.text_field :description %>
        </div>
          <%=render :partial=>"/cmanager/error_msg",:locals=>{:field =>'description',:element=>@weather_photo}%>
        <div class="form-line">  
            <label>Ελλάδα ή Εξωτερικό : </label><%=select("world", "world_id", [["Ελλάδα",1],["Κόσμος",2]])%>
        </div>
        <div class="form-line">  
            <label>Περιοχή ή Χώρα : </label><%=select("region", "region_id",Region.where("id not in (14,15,17,18)").order("name").collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] } )%>
        </div>
        <div class="form-line">  
            <%= f.label :position_id, 'Πόλη :' %><%=f.select(:position_id,Position.where("region_id=21").order("name").collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] })%>
        </div>


            </div>
            <div class="form-line">  

         <label style="margin-bottom:5px;" for="poi_poi_img">Φωτογραφία:</label>
             <%= f.file_field :weather_photo_img %>

         </div>
        <%=render :partial=>"/cmanager/error_msg",:locals=>{:field =>'weather_photo_img_file_size',:element=>@weather_photo}%>
        <%=render :partial=>"/cmanager/error_msg",:locals=>{:field =>'weather_photo_img_content_type',:element=>@weather_photo}%>

        <div class="clear"></div>
         <div style="clear:both;width: 150px; margin:30px 0 10px 60px;">
        <%= f.submit "Καταχώρηση", :class=>"button"%>
        </div>
```

and this is the controller:

```
class WeatherPhotosController < InheritedResources::Base
    layout :resolve_layout, :except=>[:photo_ajax]
    protect_from_forgery :only => [ :destroy]
    def index
        @weather_photos=WeatherPhoto.order("created_at DESC").all.paginate :page => params[:page] || 1, :per_page =>40
    end
    def photo

       @photo=WeatherPhoto.find(params[:id].to_s)

    end
    def photo_ajax

     @photo=WeatherPhoto.find(params[:id].to_s)

     respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
     # format.js {render :partial => "/weather_photos/photo_ajax_js"}
    end
  end
    def create

    @weather_photo=WeatherPhoto.new(params[:weather_photo])
     respond_to do |format|
        if @weather_photo.save
            NewsLetterMailer.contact_email(params[:weather_photo]["first_name"],
                                            params[:weather_photo]["last_name"],
                                            params[:weather_photo]["email"],
                                            params[:weather_photo]["tel"],
                                            params[:weather_photo]["description"],
                                            @weather_photo.weather_photo_img.path(:original),
                                            @weather_photo.weather_photo_img_file_name
                                            ).deliver
            format.html { redirect_to({:controller=>"weather_photos", :action=>"show", :id=>@weather_photo}, :notice => 'Το Email σας στάλθηκε επιτυχώς') }
            format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
    p @weather_photo.errors
        format.html { render :controller=>"weather_photos", :action=>"new"}
        format.xml  { render :xml => @weather_photo.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

    end
    def resolve_layout
    case action_name
    when "photo"
      "photo"
    else
      "main"
    end
  end

end
```

Can anyone spot what's wrong in all of this? Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: can you add your error trace and `routes` to your question

Comment: btw, you haven't `show` method in your controller

Comment: @usmanali where would i find these? Like i said i have no idea how rails works :-(

Comment: For every **action**, there would be a **view page** corresponding to that. In your `redirect_to` call you have mentioned `show` action but your controller doesn't have it. You can define a `show` action and a corresponding `show.html.erb` to display a thank you message.

Comment: you can just try to use `redirect_to root_path, notice: 'alert!'` to see whether it works or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a change in mail server settings and it was crushing while trying to connect to smtp server

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following line:

```
format.html { redirect_to({:controller=>"weather_photos", :action=>"show", :id=>@weather_photo}, :notice => 'Το Email σας στάλθηκε επιτυχώς') }
```

To:

```
format.html { redirect_to({:controller=>"weather_photos", :action=>"photo", :id=>@weather_photo}, :notice => 'Το Email σας στάλθηκε επιτυχώς') }
```

You don't have a `show` action, but instead have a `photo` action in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

you need add a show method in your controller

```
def show 
end
```

add show.html.haml (or erb slim etc...)in your app/views/weather_photos/

if this still not works , please paste your backtrace to see more details.

[UPDATE]

i think the problem is in layout , have you got a `main.html.erb` in your `app/views/layouts` ?

```
layout :resolve_layout, :except=>[:photo_ajax]

  def resolve_layout
    case action_name
    when "photo"
      "photo"
    else
      "main"
    end
  end
```

Comment: is there something that should go inside def show? there already is a show.html.erb file

Comment: @user3729619 nothing, just leave it blank unless you want to pass some params to `show.html.erb`

Comment: Yes there is a main.html.erb file in app/views/layouts

Comment: you should paste your error trace , it's hard to locate where the problem is .

Comment: Where can I find the error trace? I apologize i'm not much help while you're trying to solve this but it all looks like chinese to me

Comment: you need to paste which command you use to start your application, or which IDE you are using.

Comment: Is it possible to do a simple redirect to a landing page? in php i would do something like header("Location: http://www.example.com/landing-page"); Can I do something similar in rails? If it is possible where would I store this landing page?